# UINavigationController swipe to go back issue

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am creating NavigationController app which contains login and other pages. I am hiding navigation controller in login page and displaying in other pages. I have back/logout button on the left side of the second screen. when i try to drag from second screen (i am not full swipe to the login screen), navigation bar in second screen becomes hidden. It never appears again on other pages. I need to go back to login and push to second view to make navigation bar to show. When i click back/logout button instead of swipe, it works.

Any idea on solving this issue

Comment: Once you will hide a navigation bar in any controller, it will hide through out in your application, untill you will make it visibile. So use appropriate code to show or hide your navigation bar in your application.

Comment: You could manage the hiding/showing of navigation bar in `viewWillAppear` of each VC

Answer (score 0):

In your viewcontroller that you want NavigationBar visible use this code

```
-(void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated {
 [super viewWillApper:animated];
 [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
}
```